# Любая строка, кроме той, которая начинается с "temp"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярное выражение, обозначающее «любая строка, кроме той, которая начинается с "temp"»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так ?

```
^(?!temp).*
```

[explain](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%3F%21temp%29.%2A&flags=&str=temp+me)

Answer (score -1):

Можно вот так: `/^(?!temp).*?/`, но этот формат поддерживают далеко не все среды рег. выражений. А можно вот так: `/^(temp){0}.*?/` - это то же самое.

Comment: Неверно. `.*?` при таком использовании вообще раскрывается в пустую строку. А `{0}` не означает 0 вхождений. Т. е. первое наёдёт пустые подстроке в начале строк, не начинающихся с `temp`, второе - вообще всех.